# Invert Empty and Non-Empty Cells in Excel - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of cells which had the No cells marked with a `*`. I want to mark each empty cell (Yes) with a `#` and make the No cells empty (Invert the design).

To add more detail the cells are under "headers" both in rows and columns.

Eg I expect the data to be:

```
F2--? (End of F used Rows)
Unknown amount of Columns--? (End of F used Rows)
```

I'm not even sure where to start, can anybody give me a pointer? I think I'm overthinking this, but I am new to VBA and still learning.

Comment: What's the problem though?  What precisely is stopping you from doing just that?

Comment: http://codevba.com/excel/for_each_cell_in_range.htm

Comment: No, just loop over the cells: if a cell is `*` then set it empty, if it's empty then write a `*`

Comment: Feel free to delete the question here and repost it on the other site.

Comment: @BhargavRao I lost my ability to ask questions on this site because of this question and if I delete it, then it will always hurt me isn't that correct? I didn't realize I was so bad at asking questions, funny I have asked about 10 VBA questions on SuperUser lately and had no bad experiences....Posted/Accepted an answer to each question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up doing it.

```
'Invert Y/N * Logic

'Find Last Column
Dim lCol As Long
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim rng as Range
Dim rcell As Range

Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("F" & Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, Cells(2, lCol ))

    For Each rcell In rng.Cells
        If IsEmpty(rcell.Value) = True Then
            rcell.Value = "#"
        End If
        If rcell.Value = "*" Then
            rcell.Value = ""
        End If
    Next rcell
End Sub
```